# How can I use live to loop through dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use live to loop through dynamically created elements returned by **AJAX** ???  AJAX returns the HTML below ... Now after getting that HTML , how can I loop through it to retrieve the id values ?  I used `.each()` but it is not working at all , and I always use it perfectly for static `HTML` data .. how can I use .each with the `.live()` function ?  I use live on click with no problem ..

```
// this HTML is provided by AJAX dynamically
    <div id="defaults">
        <div id="badge_id" class="unique_ids database_key ui-droppable ui-sortable">

    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">
    <label class="description">Badge ID</label>
    </h1>

            <div class="ui-widget-content">
                <ol></ol>
            </div>
            <li id="0" class="ui-draggable">dsifs</li>
        </div>
        <div id="registration_type" class="unique_ids database_key ui-droppable ui-sortable">

    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">
    <label class="description">Registration Type</label>
    </h1>

            <div class="ui-widget-content">
                <ol>
                    <li class="placeholder">Add "Registration Type" here</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: which jquery version are you using `.live()` has been deprecated since 1.7, use `.on()` instead. Also post the code you tried to get the ids

Comment: Use `.live()` to loop though elements and get IDs?

Comment: In your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002067/each-jquery-isnt-looping-through-element-created-dynamically-by-php/ (which is a duplicate of this) - I've posted the exact code structure you need to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ajax is asynchronous** So you would need to handle the looping inside the `success` callback  of the request.

You use `live`  to attach events to dynamically created elements( deprecated) . Need to replace it with `.on`

> how can I use .each with the .live() function ?

`each` is used to iterate over objects and `live` to attach events. You never club both of them together.

Comment: then how can I loop through dynamically created elements .. each in this case isnt working !

Comment: You can iterate over them after the elements are appended to the `DOM
`

Answer (score 0):

You should be capturing the IDs in the AJAX `success` callback.

Here is an example of if you were using `.load()`.

```
var ids = [];

$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
    $('#saveButton').on('click',function() {
        $('#result *[id]').each(function() {
          ids.push( $(this).attr('id') );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ids are provided after the AJAX has brought back the file .. the AJAX broughts back the files with no id , it's only when a user fills in the field and click SAVE that the id is provided .. in that case , how can I ge the id of the dynamically returned HTML fields after a user inputs it ??? AJAX doesn't return the form with the ids

Comment: See my updated code above. Basically, you can attach an event to the save button after the AJAX load is complete. Then when the save button is clicked you can collect the IDs.